How to install Revenuecat on a Quasar/Vue app?
I have a quasar app that uses capacitor to create iOS apps. I am new to Revenuecat and trying to figure out the installation flow. The only relevant docs I see are the react or iconic/capacitor apps. I would think I need a vue flow, though. I see this https://community.revenuecat.com/sdks-51/installing-configuring-purchases-sdk-with-ionic-and-vue-142, but the link to the vue doc goes to the Iconic/React docs.
I may not understand the relationship between vue and iconic?
